# Jquery won't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

So hey guys, I'm trying run a html file for this angular 2 course I'm taking. After creating the dependancies for the app I downloaded them with npm. Now when I try to run the app, I get this error..

file:///Users/Rocky/Angular2-course/skeleton/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js 
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

This is how I wrote the jquery script..

```
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show us the complete path where the file is located? Looks like a path issue. Also tell us where your HTML file is located

Comment: or the file does not have permissions?

Comment: Sorry but how do i show you the path where the file is located? @RajshekarReddy

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
It means that your path to the jQuery file is wrong. Check it back.

Comment: What should I do, If the jquery does not exit in my node_modules. It should have downloaded when i installed the NPM packages. @DucFilan

Comment: Can you look in the node_modules folder and confirm that file exists? If it doesn't you can run `npm install jquery` to install it. Also... you should probably be running a local server to serve the site files. If you see "file:///" this might mean you aren't loading the html file from a server.

Comment: are u running on a Server or just in the Browser w./o running on the server first?

Answer (score 0):

If your files are in "./node_modules/jquery/dist/". Then, the script tag in your pages just looks like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

If you were using express with nodejs, a static route is as simple as this:

```
app.use('/scripts', express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/dist/'));
```

Then, any browser requests from /scripts/xxx.js will automatically be fetched from your dist directory.

Note: Newer versions of NPM put more things at the top level, not nested so deep so if you are using a newer version of NPM, then the path names will be different than indicated in the OP's question and in the current answer. But, the concept is still the same. You find out where the files are physically located on your server drive and you make an app.use() with express.static() to make a pseudo-path to those files so you aren't exposing the actual server file system organization to the client.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Another question, I'm getting an error

Comment: zone.js:1382  XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///Users/Rocky/Angular2-course/skeleton/app/main.js. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Comment: I didn't even create a file called zone.js so I don't know what it is?

Comment: Does the angular2-skeleton package present in the node_modules directory? it is configured correctly in the systemjs.config.js?
But it is a different question. You should ask it in another thread.

Comment: P/s: zone.js is a part of Angular. A Zone is an execution context that persists across async tasks. You can think of it as thread-local storage for JavaScript VMs.

Answer (score 0):

If your'e using Angular, you want to try and avoid using jQuery since Angular comes with jqLite.
Try to the version of Bootstrap made for Angular 2.
Check out https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

Also, ever though of linking them?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
```